# How to get the balance in the queue at the end of the week?

Tags: pandas

i have data:
a b sum start_time end_time:

```
  [{'A': 3,
  'B': 14,
  'C': 1.0978855136176695,
  'd1': Timestamp('2000-01-31 00:00:00'),
  'd2': datetime.date(2000, 2, 17)},
 {'A': 7,
  'B': 36,
  'C': -1.6854456807259401,
  'd1': Timestamp('2000-02-29 00:00:00'),
  'd2': datetime.date(2000, 3, 17)},
 {'A': 2,
  'B': 8,
  'C': -0.4443999007021714,
  'd1': Timestamp('2000-03-31 00:00:00'),
  'd2': datetime.date(2000, 4, 17)},
 {'A': 6,
  'B': -5,
  'C': -0.5522614635020895,
  'd1': Timestamp('2000-04-30 00:00:00'),
  'd2': datetime.date(2000, 5, 17)},
 {'A': -7,
  'B': -4,
  'C': -0.37221963217375853,
  'd1': Timestamp('2000-05-31 00:00:00'),
  'd2': datetime.date(2000, 6, 17)}]
```

if i want sum by week, i do:

```
y.reset_index().set_index("d1").groupby(['A', 'B', Grouper(freq='W-MON')]).agg({'C': 'sum'})
```

How to get the balance in the queue at the end of the week?
If i do:

```
y["LAST_DATE"] = y["D1"] + Week(weekday=6)

data['OPENING'] = [self.opening(i) for i in data["LAST_DATE"].dt.date]

def opening(d: date) -> int:
        x = y[(y['d1'].dt.date < d) & (y['d2'].dt.date > d)]
        return len(x)
```

i does not count grouping

Answer (score 0):

```
def opening(data: DataFrame, group_fields: List[Union[str, Grouper]], today: datetime) -> DataFrame:
    # Variant A
    copy_fields = group_fields.copy()
    copy_fields[-1] = 'NUMBER'
    row_list = []
    for i, row in data.iterrows():
        new_row = {f: row[f] for f in copy_fields}
        start_d = row['OPEN_TIME']
        end_d = row['RESOLVED_TIME']
        if not end_d:
            end_d = today
        for d in pandas.date_range(start=start_d, end=end_d):
            new_row['LAST_DATE'] = d
            row_list.append(new_row.copy())
    r = DataFrame(row_list)
    copy_fields[-1] = 'LAST_DATE'
    # print(r)
    # print(copy_fields)
    r = r.groupby(copy_fields).agg({'NUMBER': 'size'}).reset_index()
    r.rename({'NUMBER': 'OPENING', }, axis=1, inplace=True)
    # Variant B
    copy_fields = group_fields.copy()
    copy_fields.pop(-1)  # = 'LAST_DATE'
    min_d = data['OPEN_TIME'].min()
    to_date = data['OPEN_TIME'].max()
    print(min_d, to_date)
    r = None
    for d in pandas.date_range(start=min_d, end=to_date):
        x = data[(data['OPEN_TIME'].dt.date <= d) & (data['RESOLVED_TIME'].dt.date >= d)]
        z = x.groupby(copy_fields).agg({'NUMBER': 'count'}).reset_index()
        z['LAST_DATE'] = d
        if r is not None:
            r = r.append(z, ignore_index=True)
        else:
            r = z
    z.rename({'NUMBER': 'OPENING', }, axis=1, inplace=True)
    return r

def test_opening(self):
    values = [{'A': 3,
               'B': 14,
               'NUMBER': 1,
               'OPEN_TIME': datetime(2000, 1, 31),
               'RESOLVED_TIME': datetime(2000, 2, 2)},
              {'A': 3,
               'B': 14,
               'NUMBER': 2,
               'OPEN_TIME': datetime(2000, 1, 29),
               'RESOLVED_TIME': datetime(2000, 2, 3)},
              {'A': 4,
               'B': 8,
               'NUMBER': 3,
               'OPEN_TIME': datetime(2000, 1, 31),
               'RESOLVED_TIME': datetime(2000, 2, 5)},
              {'A': 4,
               'B': 9,
               'NUMBER': 4,
               'OPEN_TIME': datetime(2000, 1, 30),
               'RESOLVED_TIME': datetime(2000, 2, 6)},
              {'A': 5,
               'B': 3,
               'NUMBER': 5,
               'OPEN_TIME': datetime(2000, 2, 17),
               'RESOLVED_TIME': datetime(2000, 2, 17)}]
    df = DataFrame(values)
    # df[0] = df[0].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    # df = df.set_index([0])
    r = opening(df, ['A', 'B', Grouper(freq='W-MON')], datetime(2000, 2, 17))
    self.assertEqual(len(r), 21, r)
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.